# Подсчет всего времени сколько пользователь провел в голосовом канале дискорд

Tags: c#, linq, discord, entity-framework-core

Думаю, по коду будет не понятно что я написал т.к сама по себе функция большая, постараюсь вкратце рассказать. В общем метод привязан,  к ивенту который срабатывает когда пользователь вошел/вышел из голосового канала, так вот когда пользователь зашел первый раз в войс бот записывает в столбец startTime в БД datetime, аналогично когда пользователь первый раз вышел из войса. Когда пользователь зайдет 2 раз войс возьмется его прошлая запись времени и запишется в столбец OldStartTime и начнется новая запись времени аналогично с выходом. Так вот в чем же моя проблема время считывается 1 раз то есть когда я следующий раз зайду в войс время будет другим. Но я думаю мой вопрос все равно не понятен, поэтому скажу по другому как мне сделать счет времени пользователя находящегося в войсе без потери прошлого прогресса.

```
  private async Task CountUserVoiceTime(SocketUser arg, SocketVoiceState stat1, SocketVoiceState stat2)
        {
            var user = arg as SocketGuildUser;

            var UserVoiceTime = VoiceDb.GetUserVoiceTime(user.Id, user.Guild.Id);

            if (UserVoiceTime == null)
            {
                UserVoiceTime = new Voice
                {
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    GuildId = user.Guild.Id
                }; 
            }

            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();

            ISocketMessageChannel socketMessageChannel = user.Guild.GetTextChannel(myidchannel);

            if(stat1.VoiceChannel?.Name != null && stat2.VoiceChannel?.Name == null)
            {
                if (UserVoiceTime.endTime == null)
                {
                    UserVoiceTime.endTime = DateTime.Now;
                    await VoiceDb.StopTimeUser(UserVoiceTime);
                    await socketMessageChannel.SendMessageAsync("Юзер первый раз покинул войс");
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = VoiceDb.OldGetUserEndTime(user.Id, user.Guild.Id);
                    result.OldendTime = result.endTime;

                    await VoiceDb.OldStopTimeUser(result);
                    UserVoiceTime.endTime = DateTime.Now;
                    await VoiceDb.StopTimeUser(UserVoiceTime);

                    await socketMessageChannel.SendMessageAsync("Юзер покинул войс");
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                if (UserVoiceTime.startTime == dateTime)
                {
                    UserVoiceTime.startTime = DateTime.Now;
                    await VoiceDb.StartTimeUser(UserVoiceTime);
                    await socketMessageChannel.SendMessageAsync("Юзер первый раз зашёл в войс");
                }
                else
                {
                    var result = VoiceDb.OldGetUserStartTime(user.Id, user.Guild.Id);
                    result.OldstartTime = result.startTime;
                    UserVoiceTime.startTime = DateTime.Now;

                    await VoiceDb.OldStartTimeUser(result);
                    await VoiceDb.StartTimeUser(UserVoiceTime);
                    await socketMessageChannel.SendMessageAsync("Юзер зашёл в войс");
                } 
            }

            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

   //запись времени в БД
   public static async Task StartTimeUser(Voice user)
        {
            using var DbContext = new SqlDbContext();
            DbContext.Update(user);
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
  //команда выводящая время пользователя
[Command("usertime")]
        public async Task UserTimeCheck()
        {
            var profile = VoiceDb.GetUserVoiceTime(Context.User.Id, Context.Guild.Id);
            var eb = new EmbedBuilder();

            if (profile == null)
            {
                await ReplyAsync($"{Context.User.Username} your time 0 hours 0 minutes 0 second");

                TimeSpan total1 = profile.endTime - profile.startTime;

                TimeSpan total2 = profile.OldendTime - profile.OldstartTime;


                TimeSpan total = total1 - total2;

                eb.WithAuthor($"{Context.User.Username} - Your voice time");
                eb.WithDescription($"{total.Hours} hrs | {total.Minutes} min | {total.Seconds} sec.");
                await ReplyAsync(embed: eb.Build());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Уважаемый, это простейшая работа с датами, не уж то прям так сложно. Также вам говорили, чтоб вы сделали полноценную таблицу, где будет логирование всех действий пользователя, из которой вы потом без труда сможете посчитать сколько он был в войсе и когда, хоть прям календарь рисуйте. Хорошо, самое банальное, представьте, что вам нужные не даты, а числа, у вас есть у пользователя значение `Всего == 0`, вы каждое событие выхода прибавляете к этому значениют кол-во секунд, сколько он провел в канале, все, вот и ваш таймер, ведь просто, не?

Comment: как я понял, при каждом заходе пользователя должен создаваться новый столбец в БД и записываться в нем время пользователя верно?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а кстати как я DateTime прибавлю? я же только с интовыми значениями могу это сделать

Comment: Вы о чем? Столбцы в базах статичны, это как в тетрадке вы расчертили себе табличку, все, вы ее не трогаете, лишь заполняете данные. Мы вам я помню советовали сделать новую таблицу, некий журнал посещений, в которую вы будете добавлять записи по типу `12:30 | Вася | Зашел в голосовой канал`, далее `12:31 | Петя| Зашел в голосовой канал`, далее `12:35 | Вася | Вышел из голосового канала`, ну то есть некое логирование действий, по которому вы можете понять, что делал пользователь, а уж потом берете и высчитываете это все.

Comment: `а кстати как я DateTime прибавлю?` - за время в c# отвечает `TimeSpan`, делаете `DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(2, 5, 0, 0));`, получаете дату, к которой будет добавлено 2 дня и 5 часов, ну и радуетесь жизнью)

Comment: походу понял, у меня все это время считывался время в одной ячейке а нужно чтобы при каждом заходе создавалсь внизу столбца новая ячейка которая будет хранить в себе новое время пользователя который находится в войсе дальше я знаю

Comment: Решить вашу задачу можно уймой способов, от банального `стараяДата + новая`, до полноценного логирования действий, надо всего лишь чуть подумать, не знаю, на листочке себе расчертите это все, продумайте схему.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, спасибо у меня все получилось, и правда было легко, но у меня сейчас встал вопрос, чтобы бот подсчитал время я должен выйти из войса, а что если пользователь захочет проверить свое время когда он находится в войсе, как тогда поступить? если надо мой алгоритм команды 1) пользователь зашел в войс бот записал дату в бд 2) пользователь вышел из войса бот записал дату выхода отнял дату выхода с датой входа и записал результат в ячейку общее время.

Comment: А в чем трудности? Вы ведь уже все делаете, делайте тогда `бот записал дату выхода отнял дату выхода с датой входа` в момент написания команды (если он еще в войсе), где "дата выхода" будет - текущее время (DateTime.Now).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ честно говоря, не особо понял ваш, ответ, но я щас вроде придумал как решить мою ещё одну проблему

Comment: А что не понятного в моем комментарии? Вы высчитываете новое значение общего времени только в тот момент, когда пользователь вышел из войса. Ну так что мешает высчитывать это значение еще и в момент написания команды? Допустим человек ввел в чат `!myTime`, бот смотрит, в войсе он сейчас или нет, если да, то делает подсчет `предыдущие значения + (время сейчас - время входа)`, если же человек не в войсе, то `предыдущие + (время выхода - время входа)`, вроде опять же все элементарно.